# Rename "docker" privileged user group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Docker allows [running with sudo privileges](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall) by adding a user to the `docker` group. I want to rename `docker` to `docker-users`.

So I created the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with permissions `640`:

```
{
  "group": "docker-users"
}
```

Then restarted docker: `systemctl restart docker`.

But that doesn't work - the socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) still shows the default `docker` group:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sep  8 12:05 /var/run/docker.sock=
```

And my non-root (which is a member of `docker-users`) still does not have sudo-less access to the docker daemon.

How do I force docker to use the config file?

Comment: Note the term "users" implies that these are not privileged accounts. Anyone with access to the docker socket is effectively root on the host whether or not they have sudo access.

Comment: @BMitch I don't follow, do you mean `docker-users` is a bad naming choice? I have `ssh-users`, `docker-users`, etc.

Comment: It's bad naming since any "user" in that group has full root access on the host via the docker socket.

Comment: @BMitch Okay. But I don't understand why is that therefore a bad name? So what if that group's users have sudo access? It's just a group name, unless there is some convention I'm not aware of?

Comment: As long as everyone managing group membership knows those group members have root access, there's no problem. The comment about "non-root" and "sudo-less access to the docker daemon" implied otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32611). That issue shows some workarounds.